# Keep state of Gnome 3 desktop even after reboot

Tags: desktop-environments, reboot, ubuntu-gnome

Is there a way to make it so that whenever I reboot, it keeps my applications and windows that I had open before the reboot?

P.S. I'm using Gnome 3

Comment: Just to be clear, you want to maintain your desktop environment, windows, etc. after a reboot, correct?

Comment: @OwenHines  Yes, exactly.

Comment: By "pages" do you mean all the application you had open?  Otherwise, if by "pages" you mean all the tabs you had opened in your browser then you just need to go to options and check the option.  In Chrome this is in `chrome://settings/` and then `On start-up` choose the option `Continue where you left off`.

Comment: @JuanAntonio The OP never explicitly states that they are using the GNOME desktop environment. Also, I don't think the OP was wanting *just* web pages. More likely their desktop session in general.

Comment: @OwenHines I have Gnome 3, but you are right.

Comment: @OwenHines I was editing my comment when you added yours and the OP responded.

Comment: The only way is to use hibernation. The old sessions method has been removed from Unity. It is possible if someone (:)) makes a script for this.

Comment: @SandraRoss maybe edit your question to specify it is Gnome 3 that you are using.  If http://askubuntu.com/questions/201778/how-can-i-get-gnome3-to-remember-my-session does not answer your question then try to explain.  However, based on Rinzwind comment above, it does not seem to be possible.  It is too bad as I can see the use.

Comment: If you typically open the same applications, maybe this can help: http://askubuntu.com/questions/201778/how-can-i-get-gnome3-to-remember-my-session (that is what I use).